# Why I see this big number instead of zero?

Tags: c++

My Code:

```
#define A2N(a) (a>47 && a<58)?(a-48):(-1e10)
...
char *c ;
printf("Interval = %s,%d,%d \n",c,c[1],A2N(c[1]));
```

Output:

```
Interval = P00000T00:00:00                 ,48,1127219200
```

Why?!

Every thing is OK when I use %f to print the A2N(c[1]).

Comment: What is c[1], You should these thing in question. We can't simply guess and give some random reason.

Comment: we need complete, but minimal code. the current one doesn't match either criteria.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forget to write the type of c.

Comment: Well, else portion of your Macro i.e (-1e10) returns float number. Hence you will have to write %f instead of %d to get desired output.

Comment: Why the magic numbers 48 and 58? Did you really mean `'0'` and `'9'`? Why not say what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the float specifier `%f`, because the result type of the ternary expression in `A2N` is a `double`:

The "else" part uses `-1e10`, a `double`.

Comment: Without `f` postfix, I believe `-1e10` is a `double` and thus requires format specifier `%lf`.

Comment: But in this case, the else part will not execute!

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh: doesn't matter. an expression can have only one type. the compiler will choose the "wider" type.

Comment: @timrau: yes, it's `double`, and no, you don't need `%lf`, as `float`s automatically get promoted `double`s if it's a variable argument, so there's no need for distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a character is `>=65` for `uppercase characters` and `>=97` for `lowercase` .
so , everytime else part will be evaluated , which returns `double` so use `%lf` .

see [wikipedia - ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)